# delay typing need to start text on a new line after

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.25)

delay_print("Hello Evelyn!")
greetings = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!','hey']
random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)

question = ['How are you?','How are you doing?','how are you','whats up','Whats up']
responses = ['Okay',"I'm fine"]
random_response = random.choice(responses)

question1 =['whats the time?','whats is the time?','whats the time','what is the time']
watch =("TIME TO GET A WATCH!")

question2 =['whats the weather','what is the weather','whats the weather for today','whats the weather today']
weather =("THE STUFF OUTSIDE!!")

question3 =['how did you know my name','how did you know what i was called']
name =("Because I named you!")

question4 =['whats your favorite color','whats your favorite colour']
color =("Red!")

question6 =['what does the fox say','what did the fox say']
fox =("Ring ding ding ding dingeringeding Gering ding ding ding dingeringeding Gering ding ding ding dingeringeding")




while True:
    userInput = input(">>> ")
    if userInput in greetings:
        print(random_greeting)
    elif userInput in question:
        print(random_response)
    elif userInput in question1:
        print(watch)
    elif userInput in question2:
        print(weather)
    elif userInput in question3:
        print(name)
    elif userInput in question4:
        print(color)
    elif userInput in question6:
        print(fox)  
    else:
        print("I did not understand what you said")
```

I'm trying to code a chatbot. I have the delay writing working fine. I just can't figure out how to have the code start a new line after
each question!

so its says
Hello Evelyn
answer should be on a new line after question. so after the delayed text prints it should move down a line and wait for user to input answer

this is my first time on stackover flow also be gentle

Comment: i don't get it, do you want to add new line to every end of the typing? try with "\n"

Comment: where do I add \n

Comment: `delay_print("Hello Evelyn!\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a newline character `\n` after the argument you are passing inside `delay_print()`

Example: 
delay_print("Hello Evelyn!\n")

Comment: Alternatively, the function could be modified (or better yet, a wrapping function like delay_print_line could be written) to take care of it automatically, so that new lines don’t have to be added every time.

Comment: That worked great! If I want to change the wrapping function do would I change it from delay_print to delay_print_line?

Comment: just changing the function name would not give you what you want, What @Collin R is implying here is that, delay_print function can be modified to print new line when the function is called.